# Sum distance along with SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Taking reference with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57724066/is-there-a-way-to-select-several-rows-by-using-parameters/57724130) question on SO, Input graph Table is -

```
P_FROM      P_TO     DISTANCE
A           B         4
A           C         7
B           C        10
C           D        15
B           D        17
A           D        23
B           E        22
C           E        29
```

The expected answer is -

```
P_FROM    P_TO     FULL_ROUTE     TOTAL_DISTANCE
A         E        A->B->E        26
A         E        A->C->E        36
A         E        A->B->C->E     43
```

The query given in the answer is successfully retrieving the result -

```
WITH multiroutes (p_from, p_to, full_route, total_distance)
        AS (SELECT p_from,
                   p_to,
                   p_from || '->' || p_to full_route,
                   distance total_distance
              FROM graph
             WHERE p_from LIKE 'A'
             UNION ALL
            SELECT M.p_from,
                   n.p_to,
                   M.full_route || '->' || n.p_to full_route,
                   M.total_distance + n.distance total_distance
              FROM multiroutes M JOIN graph n ON M.p_to = n.p_from
             WHERE n.p_to <> ALL (M.full_route))
     SELECT *
       FROM multiroutes
      WHERE p_to LIKE 'E'
   ORDER BY p_from, p_to, total_distance ASC;
```

I think by using ORACLE syntax this query may be even more simplified, so while trying somehow I managed to get the expected result, but distance column is not correct -

```
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT(P_FROM) P_FROM
      ,P_TO
      ,CONNECT_BY_ROOT(P_FROM) || SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(P_TO, '->') FULL_ROUTE
      ,DISTANCE TOTAL_DISTANCE
FROM graph
WHERE P_TO = 'E'
START WITH P_FROM = 'A'
CONNECT BY PRIOR P_TO = P_FROM
ORDER BY P_FROM, P_TO, TOTAL_DISTANCE ASC;
```

**Output** -

```
P_FROM  P_TO    FULL_ROUTE  TOTAL_DISTANCE
A       E       A->B->E     22
A       E       A->C->E     29
A       E       A->B->C->E  29
```

I tried with the query given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683595/oracle-hierarchical-sum-distance-from-leaf-to-root) similar answer, but this also doesn't help me much. Is there any approach to get the correct total_distance using ORACLE specific syntax only.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e1a8188f7dbf318c9108c3b75165a99e) is the fiddle for your reference.

Answer (score 2):

You nearly done - your problem is to output only the distance of the last step.

Simple concatenate the *expression* or the `total_distance` using `+` and than *evaluate* it using  `xmlquery` as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56536608/4808122)

```
with dist as (  
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT(P_FROM) P_FROM
      ,P_TO
      ,CONNECT_BY_ROOT(P_FROM) || SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(P_TO, '->') FULL_ROUTE
      ,DISTANCE TOTAL_DISTANCE,
      SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(DISTANCE,'+')   total_distance_expr
FROM graph
WHERE P_TO = 'E'
START WITH P_FROM = 'A'
CONNECT BY PRIOR P_TO = P_FROM)
select P_FROM, P_TO, FULL_ROUTE, TOTAL_DISTANCE_EXPR
,xmlquery(TOTAL_DISTANCE_EXPR returning content).getNumberVal() as TOTAL_DISTANCE 
from dist
ORDER BY P_FROM, P_TO, TOTAL_DISTANCE ASC;
```

This gives the expected result, though I'm wondering if there is even simpler solution...

```
P_FROM, P_TO, FULL_ROUTE, TOTAL_DISTANCE_EXPR, TOTAL_DISTANCE
A         E     A->B->E     +4+22              26
A         E     A->C->E     +7+29              36
A         E     A->B->C->E  +4+10+29           43
```

Comment: Isn't there any better approach than this?

Comment: Not sure @AnkitBajpai [SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions198.htm#i1038266) supports character data only, so you can't perform addition. Your choice of *recursive subquery factoring* seems OK.